# Date Formatter returning Nil for specifc date string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am utilizing the SeatGeek API, and their dates are returned in the following format:

```
"date_tbd" = 0;
"datetime_local" = "2014-02-08T19:15:00";
"datetime_tbd" = 0;
"datetime_utc" = "2014-02-09T01:15:00";
```

I am trying to convert them to something more readable, such as Jan 18.  My code is as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fullDateTime];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"Mmm dd"];

cell.eventDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

However, the date is null.  Thus, the eventDate label comes out blank.

Any thoughts?  I find myself struggling with these DateFormatters regularly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letter `T` should be matched literally, therefore it must be enclosed
in single quotes in the first date format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

And the second date format should be

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd"];
```

with `MMM` instead of `Mmm` for the month abbreviation.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Have any good tuts where i could learn about NSDateFormatter and the date format string in its entirety?

Comment: @nlabhart: I know only the "official" documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1 in the "Data Formatting Guide", and the Unicode reference: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns.